# Invalid Argument Error in Jquery gzoom plugin

Tags: jquery, arguments, zooming, pan

I am using a Jquery plugin named Jquery gzoom. It's very nice script but when I test it in IE. The script show the Invalid Argument Error. The error only shows in IE.

I am wondering if anyone can figure about where in the script cause the error.

Plugin page: http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/index_it.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The script loading fine on all browsers.  The invalid argument only appear when you drag the slider towards zoomin in IE.  If you test the plugin in in IE, you will see the error.
The error does not seem to affect the functionality and only appear in IE, I install the Firebug lite, But still can't get the clear error message.

What I did it.

Put the following code in the master page,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/ui.slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.gzoom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script> 

<script type= "text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(arg) {
      $("#zoom01").gzoom({
       sW: 312,
        sH: 312,
        lW: 930,
        lH: 930,
        loaderContent: "&nbsp;"
       });
     });

</script>
```

And the following code in the content page where i want the image to zoom in and out.

```
<div class="item_zoom">
       <div id="zoom01" class="zoom">

                <asp:Image ID="testImag" ImageUrl="~/images/7409.jpg" runat="server" AlternateText="item image"/>
   </div>

       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It lies in the script itself: jquery.gzoom.js at line 107 and 113:

107:
leftFactor = leftPos/ deltaWidth;

113:
topFactor = topPos/deltaHeight;

when LeftPos or topPos is 0 en deltaWidth or deltaHeight is 0 it tries to divide 0/0 and the result is not a number

Solution:

change line 107 into:

`leftFactor = (deltaWidth==0) ? 0 : leftPos/ deltaWidth;`

and line 113 into:

`topFactor = (deltaHeight==0) ? 0 : topPos/deltaHeight;`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem lies with how you are using the plugin, not in the script itself. If you look at the samples on the page, they seem to work fine.

The browser debug messages should tell you where in the script the error occurs, although use of a browser plugin like firebug will help you isolate the error futher.

Maybe post some code of how you are calling this.